# PHP Finding how many hours of a timespan is within another timespan

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am trying to find a way to determine whether a timespan is partially or fully within another timespan. For example:

I have time entries of:

- Monday 18:30:00 to Tuesday 05:00:00,
- Monday 23:00:00 to Tuesday 05:00:00,
- Monday 20:00:00 to Tuesday 08:00:00,
- Monday 00:00:00 to Tuesday 08:00:00,

and need to find, for each one, how much of the time is within a timespan of 22:00:00 to 06:00:00. The output would need to be:

07:00:00,
06:00:00,
08:00:00,
06:00:00.

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's your experience with PHP? `time()`, `mktime()`, `strtotime()`

Comment: Could the time entries reach over multiple days? Ie could it be 01:00 Monday to 18:00 Wednesday, or even 18:00 today until 01:00 April 22 2032?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) which returns an instance of an [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Here a little example:

```
$d1 = new DateTime("Monday 18:30:00");
$d2 = new DateTime("Tuesday 05:00:00");

$limit1 = new DateTime("Monday 22:00:00");
$limit2 = new DateTime("Tuesday 06:00:00");

$within1 = $d1->getTimestamp() < $limit1->getTimestamp() ? $limit1 : $d1;
$within2 = $d2->getTimestamp() < $limit2->getTimestamp() ? $d2 : $limit2;

$interval = $within1->diff($within2);

print_r($interval);

print_r($interval);
```

outputs:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 7
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```

You can either read this attributes directly or you can use the DateInterval::format()